# Поиск элементов в списке

Tags: python

Есть список a и список b. Нужно проверить нахождение элементов b в списке a, и выдать, например, True в случае, если КАЖДЫЙ из элементов списка b есть в списке a. Если хоть одного элемента не будет, тогда False. Так же должен быть неважен порядок нахождения, может быть в разбросе. 
Делал перебором с in, но не могу реализовать вывод только при абсолютном совпадении.

Comment: `all(x in b for x in a)`

Comment: Если порядок не тот же самый - выдаёт False.

Comment: @splash58, a и b надо поменять местами

Comment: А, ну да, наоборот. Думаю автор вопроса справится :)

Comment: Да, всё работает. Разницы между этим вариантом и тем, что в ответе никакой нет, в плане неожиданных нюансов?

Comment: @type49, обновил ответ. Больше решений [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16579085/7485582).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
set(b).issubset(a)
```

Так как данное решение предполагает использование `set`, необходимо, чтобы объекты, содержащиеся в списках, были [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-hashable).

Answer (score -1):

from collections import OrderedDict
= вам в помощь! 
OrderedDict проверяет принадлежность одного итерируемого объекта к другому. Обычный dict не смотрит на порядок следования элементов внутри. dict в этом случае вернет True, тогда как OrderedDict вернет True, если порядок следования одинаковый. Перед проверкой сделайте сортировку итерируемому объекту и проверьте через OrderedDict()

```
a = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}
b = {'c': 'C', 'b': 'B', 'a': 'A'}
print(a == b)
```